# EPICOR 10 Create New BAQ Reports with SSRS

Tags: epicorerp

In Epicor 10, I've created simple New BAQ Reports using SSRS. The report generated by default have a parameter that is "TableGuid".

What the value for the parameter?

I can't delete that parameter, because it is required.
Can anyone can help me?
Or does anyone have a tutorial on how to make BAQ reports using SSRS in Epicor 10?

Answer (score 0):

When you run a SSRS report, a table is created on the SSRS server with the name of whatever your table name is with an underscore followed by a GUID. With a BAQ report the table is called BAQReportResult.

Here is what one of ours looks like with the GUID changed to protect the innocent.

```
BAQReportResult_040B6FEFB62446F8BF8A21663E4CB5C5
```

That being said, I think all you need to know about that parameter is that you need to append an underscore and it to to the end of your table in your select statement when you are defining where your data comes from in your report.

I hope this is helpful.